# Error when trying to run benchmarks on runtime but no in test benchmarks

Tags: benchmarking

i´m writing benchmarks for a pallet that manages sending tokens from assets pallet from one account to other.

I have written the benchmarks and run it with no problem using the command:

`cargo test -p pallet-name --features runtime-benchmarks`

Getting all ok.

Then I compiled the node and tried to run the benchmarks to generate the weighs file. I´m using substrate V0.9.39.

I got a `DontHavePermission` that is defined inside my pallet. that comes from the following line:

```
let asset_owner = T::Fungibles::get_owner(token)?;

ensure!(asset_owner == who, Error::<T>::DontHavePermission);
```

It means the account that is trying to do the assets transfer is not the owner.

But why my tests are leaving this error pass and not the benchmarks when run? How can I fix it?

The following is my benchmark function:

```
transfer_token_from_bank_to_user {

        let caller: T::AccountId = account("account", 0, 0);

        let _ = T::BenchmarkHelper::create_user(
            caller.clone(),
        );

        let _ = T::Fungibles::create(ASSET_ID, caller.clone(), true, AssetBalanceOf::<T>::from(1u32).into());
        let _ = T::Fungibles::mint_into(ASSET_ID, &caller, AssetBalanceOf::<T>::from(1000_0_000_000_000u128).into());
        let _ = T::Fungibles::increase_supply(ASSET_ID, AssetBalanceOf::<T>::from(1000_0_000_000_000u128).into());

        // Transfer from user to bank
        Bank::<T>::transfer_token_from_user_to_bank(
            RawOrigin::Signed(caller.clone()).into(),
            ASSET_ID,
            ASSET_ID,
            AssetBalanceOf::<T>::from(100_0_000_000_000u128).into()
        )?;

    }: _(RawOrigin::Signed(caller.clone()), // origin
        caller.clone(), // destination
        ASSET_ID, // token_bank_id
        ASSET_ID, // token_id
        AssetBalanceOf::<T>::from(10_000u32) // token_amount
    )

    verify {
        assert_last_event::<T>(Event::TransferFromBankToUser { 
            who: caller.clone(),
            destination: caller.clone(),
            token_bank_id: ASSET_ID,
            token_id: ASSET_ID,
            token_amount: AssetBalanceOf::<T>::from(10_000u32).into(), 
        }.into());
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your benchmark tests are actually being executed? Are you aware of the fact that with testing your benchmarks, the mock runtime is used and when executing the benchmarks the real runtime is used?

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas yes I´m sure the test are being executed and also that tests use mock and benchmarks use the main runtime. Also the compiler force that mock and runtime have sensical traits configured in both sides.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas can´t share the whole codebase. In which part are you interested?

Comment: Show your `get_owner` function

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas fn get_owner(asset_id: T::AssetId) -> Result<T::AccountId, DispatchError> {
  let owner = Asset::<T, I>
   ::get(asset_id)
   .map(|x| x.owner)
   .ok_or(Error::<T, I>::Unknown)?;
  Ok(owner)
 }

Comment: That seems alright. Sorry but it is hard to debug like this